# Using .Net Core MVC, How to pass value of Submit "button" to controller, while having a confirmation dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

My problem seems like it must be somewhat typical but has been overly difficult to solve. Basically, I have a single form with two submit buttons. One for "Save" and one for "Submit". I also want the user to get a confirmation dialog to before proceeding to submit. Below is an example of what I've done.

View:

```
<form asp-action="Save">
<input type="submit" name="submitType" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="submit" name="submitType" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $( "form" ).submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var submitClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    if (submitClicked == "Save") {
                        $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                    }

                    if (submitClicked == "Submit") {
                        if (confirm("Are you sure you are ready to Submit your document for Approval?")) {
                            $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $("form input[type=submit]").click(function () {
                $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
                $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(Document document, string submitType)
{
     if (submitType == "Submit")
     {
          document.ApprovalLevel = 1;
     }
}
```

Now the confirmation works without flaw, but for some reason when using preventDefault() with unbind().submit() it removes the input value for the submit button so I get a null value for submitType in the controller and consequently the submit fails. When I remove the jquery bit that posits the confirmation question, the input value for the submit button passes without fail. How can I achieve a solution where the confirmation question works while still knowing which button was used to submit to the controller.

**Edit (Solution based on Chris Pratt's simple explanation):**

View:

```
<form asp-action="Save">
//ADDED Hidden Input Parameter
<input type="hidden" id="submitForApproval" name="submitForApproval" value="false" />
<input type="submit" name="submitType" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="submit" name="submitType" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $( "form" ).submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var submitClicked = $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").val();
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    if (submitClicked == "Save") {
                    //ADDED jquery update to hidden input parameter
                        $('#submitForApproval').val(false);
                        $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                    }

                    if (submitClicked == "Submit") {
                        if (confirm("Are you sure you are ready to Submit your document for Approval?")) {
                            //ADDED jquery update to hidden input parameter
                            $('#submitForApproval').val(true);
                            $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $("form input[type=submit]").click(function () {
                $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
                $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Try binding your submit to a named function and then call `unbind` on that specific function handler. This will ensure you are only unbinding the desired function.

Comment: Include a hidden field and store in the hidden field which button was clicked - rather than store against the button.  This will then also get POST'd with the form.

Comment: You could also try `$("form").unbind('submit').submit.call($("input[type=submit][clicked=true]")[0])` to pass the button as `this` to the browser submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a submit button only makes it into the request if it's what actually submits the form. Here, you're stopping that original submit, and then manually submitting later, where the button is no longer responsible and thus doesn't send its value.

Your best bet, since you're using JS here anyways, is to set a hidden field with the value on click.